# jCarouselLite reset autoscroll interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoscroll, jcarousellite

How can I reset the auto-scroll interval on my [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) carousel after some event so that it lets you look at the content for the full interval, regardless of how far along the timer was when you clicked next or previous? Right now, if I click next or previous after 9 seconds, it scrolls again after 1 second.

In the [jCarouselLite source code](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.js) on lines 274-277 is where the auto-scroll is implemented using `setInterval`. I know you can use `clearInterval` if you have the ID returned by setInterval, but there isn't one I can get outside of modifying the source code, and I don't want to do that.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jCarouselLite itself doesn't provide any easy way to stop the auto-scrolling, which is an easier problem then do what you seem to want (?did I understand this right: You just want the autoscroll to temporarily stop on click and then continue)

### Hacky + potentially buggy way to stop the autoscroll altogether

```
var x; //hold interval id
$(function() {
    var y = window.setInterval; //backup original setInterval function
    //overwrite with new function which stores the id for us
    window.setInterval = function() {
        x = y(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
        return x; 
    };
    //now construct carousel
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev",
        auto: 500 
    });
    //now restore original setInterval function
    //as we only needed the custom one for the carousel to capture the hidden
    //internal call to setInterval
    window.setInterval = y;
});
$("#stopAutoScrollButton").click(function() {
    clearInterval(x);
});
```

---

### Real solution

As we can't get jCarouselLite to do this on its own we simulate the `auto` behavior ourself.

```
$(function() {
    var autoTime = 5000; //5s
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: ".next",
        btnPrev: ".prev"
    });
    //simulate autoscroll by simulating "click" on next link
    var x = setInterval("$('.next').trigger('click');", autoTime);
    //if stopAuto is clicked the autoscroll is suspended for autoTime
    //no matter how far along the timer already was
    $("#stopAuto").click(function() {
        clearInterval(x);
        x = setInterval("$('.next').trigger('click');", autoTime);
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, essentially I'd just like to have a mechanism to control the auto-scroll myself. I just want to create my own events to pause, resume, completely stop, and re-start the auto-scrolling. Your solution of simulating the auto-scroll behavior with custom code will be perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version with a pause on mouseover built-in. Works nicely.
http://github.com/cheald/jcarousel-lite

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers were what I was looking for, but this is what comes up when I Google 'jcarousellite reset timer', so for the next person looking to:

- Make the timer reset when you click your previous/next slide buttons
- Pause the slideshow on hover

Then this is what I put together that works for me:

```
(function($){$.fn.jCarouselLite=function(o){o=$.extend({btnPrev:null,btnNext:null,btnGo:null,mouseWheel:false,auto:null,speed:200,easing:null,vertical:false,circular:true,visible:3,start:0,scroll:1,beforeStart:null,afterEnd:null},o||{});return this.each(function(){var running=false,animCss=o.vertical?"top":"left",sizeCss=o.vertical?"height":"width";var div=$(this),a=$("#featuredlistings a.next"),ul=$("ul",div),tLi=$("li",ul),tl=tLi.size(),v=o.visible;if(o.circular){ul.prepend(tLi.slice(tl-v-1+1).clone()).append(tLi.slice(0,v).clone());o.start+=v;}var li=$("li",ul),itemLength=li.size(),curr=o.start;div.css("visibility","visible");li.css({overflow:"hidden",float:o.vertical?"none":"left"});ul.css({margin:"0",padding:"0",position:"relative","list-style-type":"none","z-index":"1"});div.css({overflow:"hidden",position:"relative","z-index":"2",left:"0px"});var liSize=o.vertical?height(li):width(li);var ulSize=liSize*itemLength;var divSize=liSize*v;li.css({width:li.width(),height:li.height()});ul.css(sizeCss,ulSize+"px").css(animCss,-(curr*liSize));div.css(sizeCss,divSize+"px");if(o.btnPrev)$(o.btnPrev).click(function(){resetAuto(); return go(curr-o.scroll);});if(o.btnNext)$(o.btnNext).click(function(){resetAuto(); return go(curr+o.scroll);});if(o.btnGo)$.each(o.btnGo,function(i,val){$(val).click(function(){return go(o.circular?o.visible+i:i);});});if(o.mouseWheel&&div.mousewheel)div.mousewheel(function(e,d){return d>0?go(curr-o.scroll):go(curr+o.scroll);});if(o.auto){autoScroll=setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll);},o.auto+o.speed);function resetAuto(){clearInterval(autoScroll);autoScroll=setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll);},o.auto+o.speed);};div.hover(function(){clearInterval(autoScroll);},function(){autoScroll=setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll);},o.auto+o.speed);});}function vis(){return li.slice(curr).slice(0,v);};function go(to){if(!running){if(o.beforeStart)o.beforeStart.call(this,vis());if(o.circular){if(to<=o.start-v-1){ul.css(animCss,-((itemLength-(v*2))*liSize)+"px");curr=to==o.start-v-1?itemLength-(v*2)-1:itemLength-(v*2)-o.scroll;}else if(to>=itemLength-v+1){ul.css(animCss,-((v)*liSize)+"px");curr=to==itemLength-v+1?v+1:v+o.scroll;}else curr=to;}else{if(to<0||to>itemLength-v)return;else curr=to;}running=true;ul.animate(animCss=="left"?{left:-(curr*liSize)}:{top:-(curr*liSize)},o.speed,o.easing,function(){if(o.afterEnd)o.afterEnd.call(this,vis());running=false;});if(!o.circular){$(o.btnPrev+","+o.btnNext).removeClass("disabled");$((curr-o.scroll<0&&o.btnPrev)||(curr+o.scroll>itemLength-v&&o.btnNext)||[]).addClass("disabled");}}return false;};});};function css(el,prop){return parseInt($.css(el[0],prop))||0;};function width(el){return el[0].offsetWidth+css(el,'marginLeft')+css(el,'marginRight');};function height(el){return el[0].offsetHeight+css(el,'marginTop')+css(el,'marginBottom');};})(jQuery);
```

Just swap it out with your current jCarouselLite script and use it just the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able/authorized to change the plugin code:

Add a variable to save the interval id to the plugins defaults

```
interval: null
```

Search for:

```
if(o.auto)
```

Take the code which is executed here and make an internal function with it like:

```
function runAuto() {
    setInterval(function() {
        go(curr+o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);
}
```

Now just save the interval to your defined variable but clear it first:

```
function runAuto() {
    clearInterval(o.interval);
    o.interval = setInterval(function() {
        go(curr+o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);
}
```

Search for the `go()` function in the plugin and add a `runAuto()`, so each time the function go is called it resets the interval.

Of course you must also add the `runAuto()` call to `if(o.auto)` so the interval starts at first.