# Need to reset a value

Tags: jquery

I'm using a jCarouselLite, and the documentation says to set auto to null to stop the scrolling.  If I have:

```
$("#myID").jCarouselLite({
    btnNext: "#next",
    btnPrev: "#prev",
    auto:3000
});
```

I thought I could pause the scrolling by doing this:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $("#myID").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: "#next",
        btnPrev: "#prev",
        auto:null
    });
});
```

Nor does auto:0 or auto:999999.

Q: Do I have to somehow unbind the original settings?

Comment: Check this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863373/jcarousellite-reset-autoscroll-interval

Comment: What he said ;) I'm deleting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $("#myID").jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: "#next",
        btnPrev: "#prev",
        auto:null
    });
})
```